# check my current gperf version

Tags: gperf

Is there a way to check the current of version of gperf on my computer? I want to use gperf3.0.3 instead of gperf3.0.4 looks like the only way to check it right now is just to reinstall

Comment: Uh... `gperf --version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said by @Sean Bright `gperf --version`